# Computed Property + Show/Hide DIV

Tags: vue.js

I am not a vue.JS programmer, but have been asked to jump in and make a few changes to an existing app. I am trying to use a computed property to show/hide a `DIV`.

The problem is the computed property is not being called after the form POST (I put a console.log statement inside the computed method to verify it's not even being called). The `findLoginProvider` method is invoked successfully and the localStorage items are set... but the `DIV` is not hidden.

Like I said, I am not a vue.JS programmer and cannot figure out why this isn't working... this is a simplified example of the real page. I really want computed properties to work because I have multiple DIV's to show/hide based on a few computed properties (so manually settings the visibility of a specific DIV is not desired)

**HTML:**

```html
<div v-if="showFindLoginProvider" :class="{'disabled': isLoading}">
  <form @submit.prevent="findLoginProvider" method="POST">
    <div>
      <label class="block text-gray-700">Email Address</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        v-model="email"
        placeholder="Enter Email Address"
        autofocus
        autocomplete
        required
        />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Methods:**

```js
findLoginProvider() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      UserService
        .getLoginProvider(this.email)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response?.status === 200) {
            localStorage.setItem("login_email", this.email);
            localStorage.setItem("login_provider", JSON.stringify(response.data));              
          } else {
              this.isError = "Error retrieving login provider";
          }});

      this.isLoading = false;
    },
```

**Computed:**

```js
showFindLoginProvider() {
      console.log("showFindLoginProvider")
      return !this.isLoggedIn && (!this.hasLoginEmail || !this.hasLoginProvider);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

> A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed

By saying that in your fnc `findLoginProvider` you need to change reactive variable to fire `showFindLoginProvider` run

```js
findLoginProvider() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  UserService
    .getLoginProvider(this.email)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response?.status === 200) {
        // will tell computed to run
        this.isLoggedIn = true
        // rest of your code
      } else {
        this.isError = "Error retrieving login provider";
      }
    });
  this.isLoading = false;
},
```

Comment: I should have included this in the original post... but `isLoggedIn` is also a computed prop

Comment: isLoggedIn() { return localStorage.getItem("access_token") !== null; }

Comment: you can see the definition of computed I paraphrase above. `isLoggedIn` will only run It read the reactive variable is changed, your code won't run since you read browser storage. you will need to set `isLoggedIn` like I've mentioned for simplicity